# getting error while using isin with case when statement in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I tried to run expression in pyspark but unable to run it, Please help me on this to use case when with .isin operator.

-> geo_region1 is new column and geo_region is an existing column with data ( BD','BT','BN','KH','CN','TW','HK','IN','ID','JP','KP','KR','LA','MY','MV','MN','MM')

```
DF2 = df2.withColumn("geo_region1", expr("case when(LOWER(geo_region).isin ('BD','BT','BN','KH','CN','TW','HK','IN','ID','JP','KP','KR','LA','MY','MV','MN','MM')) then 'APAC' end"))
```

Result: geo_region1 = APAC when condition match

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
import pyspark.sql.functuons as f
Li = ['BD','BT','BN','KH','CN','TW','HK','IN','ID','JP','KP','KR','LA','MY','MV','MN','MM']
DF2 = df2.withColumn("geo_region1",f.when(f.upper(f.col('geo_region')).isin(Li), f.lit('APAC') ).when(f.upper(f.col('geo_region')).isin(Li2), f.lit('EMEA') ).when(f.upper(f.col('geo_region')).isin(Li3), f.lit('US') ).otherwise(f.lit('unknown'))
```

Li2 and Li3 will be list you want to compare fro EMEA and us respectively.

Comment: Thanks for ur inputs......  But we have other values for EMEA and US in the geo_region column along with APAC so need to be captured those in new column geo_region1 (APAC, EMEA, US) . Please provide the logic for the same...

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Accept the answer :)